# Where can I change the TypeScript formatter in Eclipse 2022-06

Tags: typescript, eclipse, formatter, wildwebdeveloper

Sorry to ask, but I Google-ed it thoroughly, and found nothing at all!

I would like to auto-format ts (TypeScript) files. I tried setting the JavaScript formatter, but it has no effect on TypeScript code.

So where can I set the formatter for TypeScript in Eclipse 2022-06? I guess it should be part of the Wild Web installment.